# echo %cd% alias does not respond as it should

Tags: cmd, alias

I have created and alias named *pwd* for `echo %cd%` (`@DOSKEY pwd=echo %cd%`). I have saved it in bat file and configured it to autorun with command processor.

Now whenever I run the command `pwd` in my command processor it returns with the `C:\windows\system32` no matter in which path I am currently in. whereas when I run the `echo %cd%` it returns the right path I am in.

How do I solve this problem? Is it because of the parameter I am passing to echo? This parameter should update according to the path I am going in. It seems it updates just once when the command prompt is loaded with aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `%cd%` is expanded during the definition of the macro, not when it is executed.

From a batch file, you should use:

```
@DOSKEY pwd=echo %%cd%%
```

If defining from the command line, the expansion rules are different, so you would need something like:

```
DOSKEY pwd=echo %^cd%
```

But there is an even simpler method that works in all cases. The `CD` command without arguments simply lists the current directory. Just enclose the command in parentheses to prevent arguments from being passed.

```
@DOSKEY pwd=(cd)
```